# Why am I getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined" error from three.js even when I have added a requirejs shim

Tags: typescript, three.js, requirejs

When running my code I am getting the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

```
module game {
    export class Add3DScene extends dragonwings.Command {

        @inject('ResponsiveDiv')     protected _responsiveDiv:          components.ResponsiveDiv;

        public execute(): void {
            super.execute();
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089475/three-js-uncaught-referenceerror-three-is-not-defined) solution because I do not have access to the embedding html

I have however tried [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9602) but adding the shim does not seem to help and I have not been able to add the define wrapper due to lack of understand on how to incorporate this into my typescript.

I can see three.min.js as loaded in chrome debugger

I am using requirejs which seems to be causing some complications from what I have found online. Here a simplified version of my config

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "content/${gamecode}/lib",
    paths: {
        TweenMax:           "gsap/TweenMax",
        THREE:              "three/three.min",
    },
    shim:
    {
        'THREE': {
            exports: 'THREE'
        },
        'game_libs': {
            deps: ['stats', 'TweenMax']
        },
        '../app/js/main': {
            deps: ['game_libs']
        },
    }
});
```

Any help appreciated

**Edit
after looking at [Require.js not loading Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358323/require-js-not-loading-three-js) my other modules are no longer defined and so I have yet to get to the execution of the code I originally posted about
new require config

```
define("three-glue", ["three"], function (three) {
    window.THREE = three;
    return three;
});
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "content/${gamecode}/lib",
    waitSeconds: 60,
    paths: {
        TweenMax:           "gsap/TweenMax",
        three:            "three/three.min",
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            three: 'three-glue'
        },
    'three-glue': {
        three: 'three'
    },
    shim:
    {
        'game_libs': {
            deps: [
                'TweenMax'
            ]
        },
        '../app/js/main': {
            deps: ['game_libs']
        },
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Do you have the library code localy?

Comment: yes I have manually copied three.min.js into the project (which loads successfully) and included my definiton files via npm install --save @types/three

Comment: did you use the three.js map file so typescript will recognize it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Require.js not loading Three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358323/require-js-not-loading-three-js)

Comment: You need to import the module that needs to be injected in the resulting module’s require call. Try to add import 'THREE'; at the top of your module

Comment: @Louis I tried [Require.js not loading Three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358323/require-js-not-loading-three-js) and this causes other modules to no longer be defined. I have updated my original post with my new require config

Answer (score -1):

So where I added the map mattered, if it was added after the paths but before the shims then I lost all my other modules. If I added it after my shims then only the THREE module was still missing.

This was because I had forgotten to add three as a dependancy. after correcting my require config I no longer get any errors.

```
'../app/js/main': {
            deps: ['game_libs', 'three']
        },
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The order of `map` relative to `shim` does not matter. It **cannot** matter. That's basic JavaScript. `{a: 1, b: 2}` and `{b: 2, a: 1`}` contain the same information. The order of `a` and `b` does not matter.

Comment: i agree but it did

Comment: You shot yourself in the foot in some other way and attributed it to the order of the properties on the object. It is super easy to put things in the wrong place (`map` inside `paths` for instance) and RequireJS won't report the mistake. It'll just fail to behave as you expect.