# how to use videojs vr in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, video.js

I installed the videojs vr using code npm install --save videojs-vr then I used it like this: 
[image]

but this error is show:

[image]

please help me.

Comment: try running `npm i three`

Comment: @AneesIjaz not work

Answer (score 0):

Question is also asked [source stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089475/three-js-uncaught-referenceerror-three-is-not-defined) and possible issue there [Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined](https://github.com/gamestdio/three-text2d/issues/5)

Multiple issue :

- Add plugin in webpack
- Install three.js required
- Specifying character encoding in the header

EDIT :
Install three works for me

```
npm i -S three
```